# why $\mu(A_n)$ is written before $\int_{A_n} f d \mu ?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some confusion in **RCA**  book

My doubt is given below and marked  in red box

[image]

My attempt : i think  it should  be like  this  $$\frac{1}{n} \mu(A_n) \le \mu(A_n) \int_{A_n} f d\mu   \le \mu(A_n) \int_{E} f d\mu   $$

My doubt : why $\mu(A_n)$  is written  before  $\int_{A_n} f d \mu ?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f(x)>\frac{1}{n}$ on $A_n$, by monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral we have $\displaystyle\int_{A_n}f\,\text{d}\mu\ge\int_{A_n}\frac{1}{n}\,\text{d}\mu=\frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

They skipped a step.  Let $1_E$ be the function on $E$ defined by $1_E(x) = 1$ for all $x \in E$.  Then

$$\mu(A_n) = \int\limits_{A_n} 1_E \space d\mu.$$
Since $ \frac{1}{n} 1_E(x) < f(x)$ for all $x \in A_n$, we have

$$\frac{1}{n} \mu(A_n) = \frac{1}{n} \int\limits_{A_n} 1_E \space d\mu \int\limits_{A_n} \frac{1}{n} 1_E \space d\mu \leq \int\limits_{A_n} f \space d\mu.$$

Comment: $A_n\subset E$, so don't you mean $1_{A_n}$ and $\displaystyle\int_{E}$?

Comment: it's correct either way